# getting unknown type name uint8_t errors when using libgit2 as a shared library

Tags: c, low-level, libgit2, git-api

I'm trying to use the third-party library libgit2 in my C project, but I'm encountering errors when trying to compile. While using systems like github codespaces, Windows, or my MacOS X ventura workstation, I've tried the following command to compile:

```bash
$ gcc-13 -L./libgit2-1.6.4/build -I./libgit2-1.6.4/include/git2 main.c ini.c
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/sys/wait.h:110,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:66,
                 from main.c:3:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:203:9: error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
  203 |         uint8_t  ri_uuid[16];
      |         ^~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:204:9: error: ...
```

and running

```bash
clang -L./libgit2-1.6.4/build -I./libgit2-1.6.4/include/git2 -I./inih-r56 main.c
```

gives me

```
In file included from main.c:3:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:66:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/wait.h:110:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:203:2: error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
        uint8_t  ri_uuid[16];
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:204:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_user_time;
        ^
.....
```

for context, my `tree -L 2` looks like

```
├── inih-r56
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── cpp
│   ├── examples
│   ├── fuzzing
│   ├── ini.c
│   ├── ini.h
│   ├── meson.build
│   ├── meson_options.txt
│   └── tests
├── libgit2-1.6.4
│   ├── AUTHORS
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── COPYING
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── SECURITY.md
│   ├── api.docurium
│   ├── build
│   ├── ci
│   ├── cmake
│   ├── deps
│   ├── docs
│   ├── examples
│   ├── fuzzers
│   ├── git.git-authors
│   ├── include
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── script
│   ├── src
│   └── tests
└── main.c
```

and inside `libgit2-1.6.4/build`
looks like

```
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── 3.26.3
│   ├── CMakeConfigureLog.yaml
│   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   ├── CMakeRuleHashes.txt
│   ├── CMakeScratch
│   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   ├── Makefile2
│   ├── TargetDirectories.txt
│   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   ├── pkgRedirects
│   └── progress.marks
├── CTestTestfile.cmake
├── Makefile
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── deps
│   ├── http-parser
│   └── ntlmclient
├── include
│   ├── git2
│   └── git2.h
├── libgit2.pc
├── src
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── cli
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── libgit2
│   └── util
└── tests
    ├── CMakeFiles
    ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
    ├── Makefile
    ├── cmake_install.cmake
    ├── headertest
    ├── libgit2
    └── util
```

I've also successfully used the static header source pair for inih, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with libgit2. Can someone help me figure out what the issue might be? Thank you in advance for any help yo`your text`u can provide.

Comment: What's a [mcve] for your `main.c`?  Just one `#include` line?  It looks like some library forgot to `#include <stdint.h>` before using types from it, unless you included a "private" header file that wasn't meant to be included directly.  Obviously you could include `stdint.h` yourself before any of the library includes to work around the problem.

Comment: Does `main.c` that consists only of `#include <stdlib.h>` produce the same error? If not, what happens if you move `#include <stdlib.h>` to the top of `main.c`?